# Write active window to json file

Tags: database, ui-automation, power-automate

I want to write my active window to a json file (this json file needs to be in dropbox or onedrive). So if a have a word document open called "what to do" i want the current time and name of the window. 
When I have that I can use Microsoft flow to keep track of my working hours on projects with a click of a flic button

I have been working on it on the Flow side, but have no possibility to get to the active windows.

The code right now is only in Flow.

I hope some one can help me make a script that runs in the background and writes the active window to a json file that Microsoft Flow can then utilize.

Comment: Do you mean [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I cleaned up the title and question to make it a bit easier to read. I tried to clean up the question and add some relevant tags to make it easier for people to find your issue.